# How to convert vector string in to image in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vector-graphics

I am getting string like below from heartland payment gateway,

0,65535^16,58^16,55^16,52^16,48^17,45^19,42^20,39^22,35^24,32^28,31^31,29^34,28^37,28^40,29^44,31^47,32^50,34^53,35^56,38^60,40^63,43^66,45^69,48^72,51^75,53^78,57^80,60^84,62^87,66^90,68^93,69^96,69^100,66^102,63^104,60^105,57^106,53^108,49^108,46^110,42^111,39^112,35^112,32^114,28^116,24^117,21^120,17^122,14^125,13^128,13^132,13^135,15^138,17^~

They are saying it's a vector format of an image. I don't know how to convert this string in to image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code until you tried

Comment: So i ask heartland how they are saving signature image, they said they are storing it in .xcassets. We can get image with it's name directly from .xcassets. I tried but getting nil.

Comment: But in your answer you told you are getting string from your heartland payment gateway like above response.

Comment: Yes, i am getting both.